# Mac efi bootloader doesn't show ubuntu, and GRUB load automatically

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, bootloader

Right now when I start my computer GRUB loads, and then I can select if I want to start either OS X or Ubuntu, and if I start the computer holding down the alt-option key to load Mac's efi bootloader Ubuntu doesn't show up. And therein lies the problem, how can I set things up so when I start the computer it simply boot's into OS X, and when i Load Mac's efi loader I can select to boot Ubuntu, through GRUB? I used to have it set up like this, I don't remember what I did as it was a few years ago. Might be a different way to set things up, if you catch the gist of my problem, I don't use Ubuntu a lot and it is rather cumbersome to load Apple's efi bootloader every time I want to start OS X.

Answer (score 1):

"[efibootmgr](http://linux.die.net/man/8/efibootmgr) is a userspace application used to modify the Intel Extensible Firmware Interface (EFI) Boot Manager. This application can create and destroy boot entries, change the boot order, change the next running boot option, and more."

```
sudo efibootmgr -v
```

will return a list of your present boot entries. For example:

```
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 5 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0080
Boot0000* ubuntu
Boot0080* Mac OS X
```

Change order:

```
sudo efibootmgr -o 0080,0000
```